# jboss 7 cpu monitoring

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jmx

I want to monitor ""Jboss 7 as"" CPU usage memory but not CPU usage time, can I do this using JMX ? when I write this function, I get the cpu time, not cpu memory...

```
public String getCpuUsage(){
    try {
        Method m=op.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessCpuTime");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object value=null;
        value=m.invoke(op);
        return value+"";
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use [JConsole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JConsole)

Comment: i use it but i dont find wich MBean !